# "Unable to connect to the ASP.NET Development Server" message in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, tortoisesvn

I just checked out an ASP.NET MVC 3 web project using TortoiseSVN. I opened it in vs2010 and successfully built it. But when I try to run the project, vs2010 gives me an error with the following message "Unable to connect to the ASP.NET Development Server". When I open the development server dialog via icon in notification area and try to browse through the link in this dialog a web page opens with "HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden".

This looks quite odd, as when I create a new MVC project in the same solution and try to run it, it runs normally. This problem occurs only with the aforementioned project.

Please share any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

1. Open web.config
2. Remove everything in the `<system.web>` section
3. Run the project (it should work now)

Undo your web.config changes and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I already got around by re-installing windows (even re-installing visual studio didn't help).

Answer (score 0):

Try to change assigned port in project properties-> Web-> set specific port instead of auto assign.